# Materializecss slider first item not showing

Tags: jquery, css, slider, materialize

I'm trying to load materialize slider with skrollr, it's working but only the first item of the slider is on opacity: 0; condition

[image: First Item Not Showing]

And after waiting couples second it's showing its 2nd item.

[image: 2nd slider showing]

And this is my HTML code

```
<div id="story"
data-0="display: none;"
data-1="display: block; top: 200%;"
data-2000="top: 0%;"
data-3000="top: -100%;"
>
<div id="story-overlay"></div>
<div id="story-title">
        <p class="uppercase">Love Story</p><br>
        <p class="date"><span class="uppercase">September</span> 20th, 2015</p>
</div>

<div id="story-carousel">
    <div class="slider">
        <ul class="slides">
            <li>
                <div class="caption left-align">
                    <!-- Title -->
                    <h3>How We Met</h3>
                    <!-- Story -->
                    <h5>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum</h5>
                </div>
            </li>

            <li>
                <div class="caption left-align">
                    <!-- Title -->
                    <h3>How We Met</h3>
                    <!-- Story -->
                    <h5>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum</h5>
                </div>
            </li>

            <li>
                <div class="caption left-align">
                    <!-- Title -->
                    <h3>How We Met</h3>
                    <!-- Story -->
                    <h5>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum</h5>
                </div>
            </li>

            <li>
                <div class="caption left-align">
                    <!-- Title -->
                    <h3>How We Met</h3>
                    <!-- Story -->
                    <h5>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum</h5>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

And this is my CSS code

```
#story #story-carousel {
position: absolute;
display: block;
top: 0;
left: 0;
height: 400px;
width: 100%;
z-index: 1;
background-color: transparent;
}

#story #story-carousel .slides {
z-index: 1;
background-color: transparent;
padding: 200px;
padding-top: 20;
}

#story #story-carousel .slides h3 {
font-weight: 100;
text-transform: uppercase;
color: #fff;
}

#story #story-carousel .slides h5 {
padding: 20px;
font-size: 1.1rem;
color: #fff;
font-weight: 100;
}

#story #story-carousel .slider .indicators {
z-index: 999;
}
```

It'll be great if someone can help me,
Thanks before.

Answer (score 0):

adding an `<img>` should do it. it's not the most elegant way nor the best, but a lot of websites using materializecss have done it.

for example this [eyerys website](http://www.eyerys.com/). from the source you can see that there is an `<img>` tag just after the first `<li>` tag.

the trick has been documented [here](https://github.com/Dogfalo/materialize/issues/1244)